# Ionic v1 error only in POST 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: rest, post, ionic-framework, cors, restful-url

I have an error using Ionic v1 when I make a POST call. GET and PUT calls works, but only POST calls don't work, the error is this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/FoodDrinkDispener/rest/user. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I tryed this POST request in "Postman" and it works very well. I don't know what is the problem is a mistery. I found something in internet but I read that there are some things to change in some configuration files not present in my project (maybe for the Ionic version)

Comment: Are you getting this error while inside Chrome, using `Ionic Serve`? Or are you getting this error on the real device?

Comment: using ionic serve! I tryed in my device but it doesn't work, but I don't know if there it is the same error. THere is a way to read the console from the smartphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using "Moesif Origin & CORS Changer" Google Chrome Estension.